# Show GMaps polylines on Windows Phone Map control

Tags: android, google-maps, windows-phone, here-api

I'm working on an app that has also an Android version, and the client would like to use Google Maps on both apps, but I don't think it's possible for Windows Phone because there is no GMaps library available. 
The Android app creates a route, and it sends to the API an encoded string with the polylines which is stored in the database. Now I have to take that string, get the polylines, and show it on my Map control. Do you think there are any compatibility issues? I'm thinking that Google and Microsoft use different Map providers so I don't want to have different routes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to point out to the client that displaying Google Maps using the Windows Phone Map control is explicitly prohibited in the [terms and conditions](http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/devcenter/en-us/legal/MSFT_Mapping_API_Terms.pdf) stated by Microsoft, which will probably cause problems later on when you submit an app to the Windows Store.

I'm no lawyer, but this section of the Map Control T&Cs seems pretty clear:

> **Use Restrictions.**
>
> There are some restrictions on your use of the Mapping APIs.
>
> You may  not:  ...
>
> - integrate the Mapping APIs or any of its content with any other    mapping platform;

You have several options here. Either

1. Use Google Maps on your Android native Version and WP Maps Control (i.e. HERE Maps) on the WP native version - i.e. have a completely divergent codebase. The fact that the routing algorithms are different would mean that you could end up with different results. The biggest upsides of this approach is that the WP user would be seeing the "normal" map for the phone, and things such as routing and geocoding would come direct from the device without a need for a connection
2. Write a single mobile HTML 5 client which is based on the map of your choice and accesses a single source for routing etc. This has the advantage of being a single type of map, but you would need to ensure that the app is fully cross browser (i.e. supports all the quirks of IE10+)  and also HTML5 solutions typically aren't as "native" looking.
3. Some combination of the above - e.g. a WP app, an Android App and web-based solution

Which route you go down is entirely up to you and the depth of the pockets of your client.

Comment: I ended up using the Google API for locations with the map from Microsoft. I draw the polylines directly on the map even though they don't match completely. I don't think that there will be any problems during certification because I'm only using the Google API, not Google Maps tiles.

Comment: If you read the T&Cs carefully, the restriction is on APIs from another **mapping platform**, not specifically the **map tiles**, so I'm not sure if that will help.